# How do I use wget to download images from a list without creating duplicates?

Tags: shell, wget

I have a list that has urls such as:

```
http://imgur.com/img1.jpg
http://imgur.com/img2.jpg
```

(It updates every now and then.)

I currently use `wget`:

```
wget -i imglist -P c:/filename/
```

But if I run it once again, it duplicates the images: if there's already `image1.jpg`, it names it `image1.jpg.1`. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Check out [no-clobber](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html) flag

Comment: I tried that, i got: http://imglist/
Resolving imglist (imglist)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘imglist’

Answer (score 0):

You could compare both files & keep only the newest among both using `-N` flag

```
      wget -N -i imglist -P c:/filename/
```

Here are some use cases for wget:

http://www.editcorp.com/personal/lars_appel/wget/v1/wget_7.html